# Sharepoint REST API 403 Error

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

I've setup an App in Azure using instructions from various places, including:
http://www.ktskumar.com/2017/01/access-sharepoint-online-using-postman/
http://tech.bool.se/basic-rest-request-sharepoint-using-postman/

I've successful authenticated using the client_credentials flow and received an access token:
[image]

However, when I tried to call various endpoints, I always get a 403 error:
[image]

Tried other endpoints such as https://cityofstirling.sharepoint.com/_api/contextinfo but all resulted in the 403 error.

I've granted full access to collections for the App. Does anyone have any ideas that I could explore further? Thanks for your help.

Comment: you might want to add the version of SharePoint you're using and the how authentication is set up.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through this article which is posted by "Shantha Kumar Thambidurai". He explained very clearly, about calling the SharePoint API from Postman.

http://www.ktskumar.com/2017/01/access-sharepoint-online-using-postman/

Answer (score 0):

Thx for that link. It was one of the links that I posted initially. I managed to solve the issue. My error was that I used the "App Registration" function within Azure rather than using the linked App Registration:

https://.SharePoint.com/_layouts/15/appregnew.aspx